# console.logの出力結果をブラウザ上で表示したい

Tags: javascript

下記のconsole.logの出力結果をブラウザ上で表示するにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか？

```
let greeting = "Hello world";
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        console.log(greeting);
}
```

Comment: これらの記事が参考になるかもしれません。[how to display web browser console in a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59491716/9014308), [Overriding console.log, etc to display inside HTML view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67184346/9014308) 試してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: 出力結果をブラウザ上に表示するとは、consoleのように表示したいということですか？それとも、単純に変数の内容を[HTMLとして書き出したい](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)ということですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

アイデアとしてはconsole.logに入力された引数を、DOMを利用してHTMLの要素上に設定するようにすればいいかもしれません。
ブラウザ上に出力結果が表示されます。
サンプルコードは以下のものです。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script>
// ページ読み込み時のイベントを登録
window.onload = function(){
    // ブラウザ上に表示する文字列を保持する一時変数
    let outstr = "";
    // console.logの挙動
    console.log = (...args) => {
        for(let arg of args){
            // console.logに入力された文字列を改行つきで保持
            outstr = outstr + arg + "<br>";
        }
        // HTMLのid="console"に対して文字列outstrを設定する
        document.getElementById("console").innerHTML = outstr;
    }

    // 当質問のコード
    let greeting = "Hello world";
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        console.log(greeting);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- ブラウザ上の出力先 -->
<p id="console"/>
</body>
</html>
```